# Rails n-level multi select categories

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, drop-down-menu, categories

I have a `rails 3.2` project in which I have `Projects`, `Categories`, and `ProjectCategories`.

A project:

```
has_many :project_categories
has_many :categories, through: :project_categories
```

A Category:

```
has_many :subcategories, class_name: 'Category', foreign_key: 'parent_category_id', dependent: :destroy
belongs_to :parent_category, class_name: 'Category'

has_many :project_categories, dependent: :destroy
has_many :projects, through: :project_categories
```

A ProjectCategory:

```
belongs_to :category
belongs_to :project
```

So a category has n-levels of nesting in it.

I am trying to create a form where the user selects 1 or more top level categories for a project. Based on these selections, the user sees their children categories and can select 1 or more of these. This is repeated until there are no more child levels.

All of these selections are saved as a `ProjectCategory`.

Are there any good libraries that will perform something like this?

Has anyone had a similar situation and can recommend a better layout to perform this?

I have looked into `ancestry`, `awesome_nested_set` and other nested set gems, none if which seems to have any views helpers to accomplish this.

Also rails `grouped_collection_select` does not seem to be able to handle this.